# C++ need to use .good instead of .eof

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

I'm a total beginner and I have this function in which I use .eof however I was told that it's not a good idea since that would not work with linux and that I should use .good 
So could you tell me what I would do and how I should modify it

```
std::string ex_file_licensing::getUsedLicense(const std::string &FlexLMfileName){

        std::ofstream openFile;
        std::string line;
        std::string tempString;
        std::string testResult;
        size_t start_pos;
        size_t stop_pos;
        std::string retour ="";
        filebuf fb;
        fb.open (FlexLMfileName.c_str(),ios::in);
        istream toOpen(&fb);


        if(toOpen.eof()){
            while(!toOpen.eof()){
                getline(toOpen,line);
                if(line.find("Checkout") != std::string::npos ){   
                    start_pos = line.find(":"); 
                    tempString = line.substr(start_pos+1);
                    stop_pos = tempString.find("/");
                    testResult = tempString.substr(start_pos, stop_pos);
                }
                else if (line.find("FLEXnet") != std::string::npos ){   
                    start_pos = line.find("FLEXnet"); 
                    tempString = line.substr(start_pos+1); 
                    stop_pos = tempString.find("Feature");
                    testResult = tempString.substr(start_pos, stop_pos);
                }
                cout << testResult << endl;
                retour.append(testResult);
            }

            fb.close();
        }

        return retour;
    }
```

Comment: I think that the `if(toOpen.eof()) {` is a bug, on any OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop like this:

```
while (getline(toOpen, line)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use neither: the stream has a built-in conversion operator to boolean, you can thus test it simply with `if (toOpen)` or `while(toOpen)` and it *just works*.

By the way, your `if` condition looks wrong as it only executes the code within if the filestream reached the EOF character.

Comment: yep, The if condition is wrong.

Comment: hi so If I put `while(toOpen)` instade of `while(!toOpen.eof())` it would give the same result ?

Comment: Not quite, just because the stream is okay before you start consuming does not mean it will stay okay forever. You would need to test after each extraction, which is why @sth recommended `while(getline(...))`.